# Get a child attribute from a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I need help writing a query that checks if an `event` occurs on a certain date.**

An `event` has_many `days`, and `day` has an attribute called `:date` which I'm trying access, but can't seem to get to it.

Code:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :days_attributes

  has_many :days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days

  scope :occurs_on, lambda {|date| where(Day.first.date => date)}
end

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :event_id
  belongs_to :event

  validates :date, presence: true
end

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.occurs_on(Date.today)
  end
end
```

In my view I can show the date like this: `<%= event.days.first.date.strftime("%A, %B %e") %>` so I thought that'd work in my model, but it doesn't. I get a `undefined method 'to_sym'` error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you'll want to do a `join` in your scope:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :days_attributes

  has_many :days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days

  scope :occurs_on, lambda {|date| joins(:days).where("days.date = ?", date)}
end
```